# Renaming a file name to exclude the first couple parts Powershell

Tags: powershell, rename

I have over a million files like such: First_Last_MI_DOB_ and lots more information. Is there a way I can run a rename script that can remove just the first, last, Mi, and DOB from the file name, but keep the stuff after that? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Would be good if you could include your attempts and a real example of what a file name looks like and how you want it to look after the rename.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I know just the basics, like how to -replace things. And how to rename something by adding something in front of behind the file name. So an example of a file would be: x-John_Doe_._DOB_01-11-1990_M_ID_000000_TitleofDocument_DateofDocument_Docpagenumber_ Where 'M' is male or female and 000000 is their ID number. After the remove, I would just want ID_000000 .... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Edited from my answer to this question: [Parse and Switch Elements of Folder Names using Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/937309/parse-and-switch-elements-of-folder-names-using-powershell)

```
# Path to folder
$Path =  '.\'

# Regex to match "ID_000000..."
$Regex = 'ID_\d+.*$'

# Get all objects in path
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path |
    # Select only objects that are not directory and name matches regex
    Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match $Regex} |
        # For each such object
        ForEach-Object {
            # Rename object
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $Matches[0]
        }
```

**UPDATE #1 :** It seems that you need to write a regex that will match a required part of the name and then use it in to rename a document.

Assuming that file name is `x-John_Doe_._DOB_01-11-1990_M_ID_000000_TitleofDocument_DateofDocument_Docpagenu‌​mber_`, here is couple of the examples:

---

- Regex (https://regex101.com/r/gI0fZ2/2): `(ID_\d+.*)$` - will match `ID_{ONE_OR_MORE_DIGITS}{ANY_CHARACTERS}`
- Result:`ID_000000_TitleofDocument_DateofDocument_Docpagenu‌​mber_`

---

- Regex (https://regex101.com/r/gI0fZ2/1): `\d{4}_(M|F)_(.*)$` - will match `{4_DIGITS}_M_{or}_F_` and capture everything after that in capture group.
- Result:

  - 1st match - `M`
  - 2nd match (the one to use) - `ID_000000_TitleofDocument_DateofDocument_Docpagenu‌​mber_`

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> All the names in each file are different, a long with different ID's.
>   For example: `John_Doe_DOB_01/01/01_ID_000000` and the next file name
>   could be: `John_Smith_DOB_01/02/01_ID_100000` and so on. I am thinking I
>   would just want to read the file name in as a string, split it by _
>   and then make the new file name the stuff from [4] and after. Is there
>   a way to do that?

Sure, you can do that, but I'd recommend a regex approach, because it would work for every filename that has `ID_0xxxx` string, no matter of what. I've modified my initial example with first regex, so it should work for you.

But if you'd like to try splitting approach, here is how to do it:

```
# Path to folder
$Path =  '.\'

# Filename separator
$Separator = '_'

# Get all objects in path
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path |
    # Select only objects that are not directory and name matches regex
    Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
        # For each such object
        ForEach-Object {
            # Generate new name
            $NewName = ($_.Name -split $Separator | Select-Object -Skip 4) -join $Separator

            # Rename object
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName  $NewName
        }
```

Comment: Each first and last name will be different eventually, is there a way I can check for that?

Comment: An example would be: aaa_aaa_ and the next file could be aab_aaa as the first and last names.

Comment: @ZachSmith Oops, I didn't realize that `First_Last_MI` is reffering to the fist last and middle name (English is my second language). Basically you need a regex, and it's important to know how filename is constructed to get it right. See update and let me now what regex will work for you.

Comment: All the names in each file are different, a long with different ID's. For example: John_Doe_DOB_01/01/01_ID_000000 and the next file name could be: John_Smith_DOB_01/02/01_ID_100000 and so on. I am thinking I would just want to read the file name in as a string, split it by _ and then make the new file name the stuff from [4] and after. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @ZachSmith Can be done, by I don't recommend it. See update for example.

Comment: That really worked well. Thank you very much I will be using this in my upcoming projects a lot. Thank you again!